# NiFi adding custom lib jar

Tags: apache-nifi

We are trying to add additional DB jar's available under `lib/` folder of the nifi deployment. How to have an additional jar to be available under `lib/` once the nifi is built?

Comment: could you please clarify what is the problem when you put jar into lib/ ?

Comment: I don't want to copy the required Jars, after the app is built. I need the jars to be available in `lib/` after the NiFi is built. What modifications that I have to make to achieve this?

Comment: do you mean you are building nifi from sources?

Comment: @daggett Yes...

Comment: just look how other jar libraries included into `nifi/lib` at `NIFI_SOURCES/nifi-assembly/pom.xml` and just add required maven dependencies into pom.xml. but why you are building it from source? why just not to get the binary zip and add required jars into it?

Answer (score 3):

Adding JARs to `lib/` is not recommended, even if you are building your own NiFi distribution.

If you are not building your own distribution, and you are using a [DBCPConnectionPool](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html) to connect to the database, you can put the JARs wherever else you like, and point to them with the "Database Driver Location(s)" property. This is the recommended method for adding necessary database driver JARs.

If you are building your own distribution, I believe you can add the driver as a Maven dependency to the [nifi-dbcp-service POM](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-bundle/nifi-dbcp-service/pom.xml). Note that you would be subject to any Licensing requirements imposed by the included driver. For example, Oracle and MySQL drivers are not included with Apache NiFi because their license is not Apache-friendly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find somewhere else that putting jar in Nifi's `lib/` folder is not reccommended. Could you tell me why it is that?

Comment: The JARs in the lib folder are loaded by a parent classloader that all child classloaders inherit. That can cause problems if two NARs need different versions of the same artifact, as both would load the same one from lib if it were located there.